# How to use jQuery change event on dropdownlist to populate another dropdownlist using an ActionResult in the Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use the change event of a dropdown to call an ActionResult in my controller in order to populate another dropdown.

Here is the jQuery that I've tried:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#CertificationId').change(function () {
            var data = {
                certificationId: $('#CertificationId').val()

            };

            var certificationId = $('#CertificationId').val();
//            $.post('@Url.Action("AjaxGetCourseOptions", "WorkerCertifications")', {certificationId : certificationId}, $(this).parents('form:first').serialize(), function (data) {
//                //$('#form').children().remove().append(data);
//            }, 'html');

//            var url = '@Url.Action("AjaxGetCourseOptions", "WorkerCertifications")';
//            var certificationId = $('#CertificationId').val();
//            $.post(url, { certificationId: certificationId }, function (result) {
//                alert('success');
//            });

//            $.getJSON('/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/', data, function (result) {
//                alert(result.message);
//            });

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("AjaxGetCourseOptions", "WorkerCertifications")', data, function (result) {
                alert(result.message);
            });

//            $.getJSON(this.href, data, function (result) {
//                alert(result.message);
//            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Here is the code from the Controller:

```
public ActionResult AjaxGetCourseOptions( string certificationId )
    {
        var viewData = new WorkerCertificationViewModel
        {
            //CourseOptions = ScheduledCourse.GetActive().ToSelectList(x => x.Id, x => x.Id),
            CourseOptions = ScheduledCourse.GetAvailableCourses(Convert.ToInt64(certificationId)).ToSelectList(x => x.Id, x => x.Id)

        };

        viewModel.CourseOptions = viewData.CourseOptions;

        return Json( new {message = "Test"},
                     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );
    }
```

I can't seem to get the jQuery to call the code in the Controller.  How can I accomplish this?

### Update

I am still having an issue getting this to work.  This is the url of the page before the change event fires for the dropdown http://mylocalhost.com/camms/WorkerCertifications/Insert/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843

After the change event fires, I have a hard coded (for now) url that I want to post to but it's getting appended to the current url.  Any idea how to fix this?  This is the url that it is trying to post to:  http://mylocalhost.com/camms/WorkerCertifications/Insert/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/camms/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/?certificationId=10916

The url should look like this:  http://mylocalhost.com/camms/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/?certificationId=10916

I had to remove the local host and port in order to save this update.

Comment: @Url.Action("AjaxGetCourseOptions", "WorkerCertifications")' it seems like here you're calling it wrong. You should call it like this: Url.Action("YourController", "AjaxGetCourseOptions"). To avoid these errors I suggest you use T4MVC.

Comment: The @Url.Action seems to be passing a null/empty string value ''. When I try using this:  $.getJSON('/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/', data, function (result) {
                alert(result.message);
            });  I get a 404 error.

Comment: can you access the url from the browser directly? Have you tried looking into the response with Firebug or Chrome?

Comment: When I try the url directly into Chrome, I get a 404.  This is the url, of course it does you no good since it's on my localhost but you can see what it looks like.  Thank you very much for your help, I cannot get this to work.  URL:  http://localhost:56452/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/?certificationId=10916

Comment: Install fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/. Then use it to see what's wrnog with your request... If you still have problem post your fiddler response log here...

Comment: Are you making it into your Controller?  You can check via Debug.

Comment: I can't install the fiddler due to our proxy server having it blocked, just tried to download it...denied.  I am not making it back into my controller, just get a 404 error once the jquery fires the $.getJSON.

Comment: Just tried this and got a 404 as well:  var url = '/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/';
            $.post(url, { certificationId: certificationId }, function (result) {
                alert('success');
            });

Comment: This is from the debugger in Chrome:  POST http://localhost:56452/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/ 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
send jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
f.(anonymous function) jquery-1.6.2.min.js:18
(anonymous function) 14843:504
f.event.handle jquery-1.6.2.min.js:17
i.handle.k

Comment: sorry, was missing a piece of the url, got into my controller now.  Thank you to all who replied.

Comment: For some reason it's not posting now and I'm using this code:  var url = 'camms/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/?certificationId=' + certificationId;
            
            $.post(url, { certificationId: certificationId }, function (result) {
                alert('success');
            });           It's changing the url to this:  http://localhost:56452/camms/WorkerCertifications/Insert/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/camms/WorkerCertifications/AjaxGetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843/?certificationId=10916

Comment: It's appending the url that I'm trying to use for the post to the current url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by the following:

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CertificationId').change(function (evt) {
        var data = {
            certificationId: $('#CertificationId').val()

        };

        var certificationId = $('#CertificationId').val();
        $.ajax({
            //url: "/camms/WorkerCertifications/GetCourseOptions/SysAdmin/Worker/Certifications/14843",
            url: window.location.href.replace('Insert', 'GetCourseOptions'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { certificationId: certificationId },
            success: function (courseOptions) {
                // courseOptions is your JSON array
                var $select = $('#CourseId');
                $select.children().remove();
                if (courseOptions.length > 0) {
                    var listItems = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < courseOptions.length; i++) {
                        listItems.push('<option value="' +
                            courseOptions[i].Value + '">' + courseOptions[i].Text + '</option>');
                    }
                    $select.append(listItems.join(''));
                }

                //                    $.each(courseOptions, function (i, option) {
                //                        $('<option>', {
                //                            value: option.Id
                //                        }).html(option.Id).appendTo($select);
                //                    });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

In the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCourseOptions( string certificationId = "0")
    {
        var list = ScheduledCourse.GetAvailableCourses(Convert.ToInt64(certificationId)).ToSelectList(x => x.ScheduledCourseId, x => x.ScheduledCourseId);

        var result = new JsonResult();

        result.Data = list.ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I'm populating the dropdown list like this:

There are two dropdown lists job categories and jobs. Once you select a job category the jobs list gets populated.

```
     function ListingJobs()
    {
        var job_ID = $( "#JobCatID" ).val();

        $.ajax( {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetJobs")',
            data: { JobCatID: job_ID },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function ()
            {
                alert( "An error occurred." );
            },
            success: function ( data )
            {

                var items = "";

                $.each( data, function ( i, item )
                {

                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.values + "\">" + item.texts  + "</option>";
                } );

                $( '#JobID' ).html( items );
            }
        } );
    }

    $( '#JobCatID' ).change( function ()
    {
        ListingJobs();
    } );
```

And in your controller you must supply a value-name pair converted to json.