# How to get Selected dropdownlist value in mvc4 and based on selection need to populate in another dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

my jquery is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$("#drpId").change(function(e) {
    firstDDLValue = $("#drpId").val();
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetDataForSecond", "Login")', { fstValue: firstDDLValue }, function (e) {
        var select = $("#secondDDLID");
        select.empty();
        $.each(result, function (index, Data) {
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: result.Value,

            }));
        });
    });
});
});
```

My controller code is

```
  public JsonResult GetDataForSecond(string fstValue)
    {
        Domain obj = new Domain();
        var data = obj.LoadSubDomain(fstValue); return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in data i am getting all the values of second dropdown but in view its not binding.
and my view code is just like this

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @{
var data = ViewBag.MyData;
            <select name="drpId" id="drpId">
                <option value="yourvalue">Select DomainName </option>
                @foreach (var te in data)
                {
                    <option>@te.DomainName</option>

                }
            </select>
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DomainName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select name="secondDDLID" id="secondDDLID">
            <option value="yourvalue"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.. do you want the second drowpdown to be populated after some button is clicked or it should be populated on the page load?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505364/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-jquery-change-event-on-dropdownlist-to-populate-another

Comment: i want second dropdown to be populated on change of 1st dropdown

Comment: Please show what obj.LoadSubDomain(fstValue) will return eq: Name, UserId etc..

Comment: its returning name based on the first selection

Comment: I have updated my answer using your requirement. Use that code as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

In your view add this script:

```
$("#drpId").change(function () {
        firstDDLValue = $("#drpId").val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("GetDataForSecond", "Login")', { fstValue: firstDDLValue }, function (result) {
            var select = $("#secondDDLID");
            select.empty();
            $.each(result, function (index, Data) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: Data.Value,
                    text: Data.Text
                }));
            });
        });
    });
```

And method to bind second ddl in controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetDataForSecond(string fstValue)
    {
        Domain obj = new Domain();
        var result = obj.LoadSubDomain(fstValue);
        IList < SelectListItem > Data = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
           Data.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = result[i].Name,
                Value = result[i].Name,
            });
        }
        return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I think a better approach would be to put the dropdown itself in a partial view and just return that partial view with ajax. What say?

Comment: return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); data i am getting all the values but its not binding to 2nd dropdown

Comment: Please edit your question above and show what you are using to bind data in second dropdown. Because above code is working code.

Comment: i posted the code again just check it ,if u ve anu doubt just ask me

Comment: Change result.Value to Data.Value in second dropdown bind method

Comment: still its not working as i am new to mvc4 and jquery i am not getting how to fix it?